# I need help my lua text rpg and I dont know what did I did wrong tho

Tags: lua

There is my code:

```
elseif command == "attack Frog" then
    if room == "0001" then
      monster.hp = 5
      monster.dmg = 2
      while monster.hp > 0 or player.hp > 0 do
        monster.hp = monster.hp - player.dm
        print("Monster Health: " .. monster.hp)
        if monster.hp > 0 then
          player.hp = player.hp - monster.dmg
          print(player.un .. "Health: " .. player.hp)
        end
      end
      if monster.hp < 1 then
        print("Victory!\r\n+10XP +2Gold")
        player.xp = player.xp + 10
        player.gd = player.gd + 2
      else
        print("YOU DIED!!!")
        i = 0
      end
    end
  end
```

The elseif is because there is more commands but the point is for some reasons it will only type the monster Hp and it will decrased until eternity :(

I dont know how to fix it and Im too coward to delete it and start it over :(
Here are the player variables

```
player = {}
player.xp = 0
player.mx = 16
player.lv = 1
player.dm = 1
player.hp = 20
player.mh = 20
player.gd = 0
player.un = ""
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
      while monster.hp > 0 or player.hp > 0 do
        monster.hp = monster.hp - player.dm
        print("Monster Health: " .. monster.hp)
        if monster.hp > 0 then
          player.hp = player.hp - monster.dmg
          print(player.un .. "Health: " .. player.hp)
        end
      end
```

At the beginning both monster and player have hp > 0.
You subtract the respective damage from the hitpoints.

Let's print the hitpoints over time:

```
monster  player
   5       20
   4       18
   3       16
   2       14
   1       12
   0       10 <- at this point you stop dealing dmg to the player
  -1       10
  -2       10
  ...
```

So the condition `monster.hp > 0 or player.hp > 0` will remain true forever.
You should stop the fight when one of the opponents is dead. Either break the loop or simpler replace the `or` in `monster.hp > 0 or player.hp > 0` with `and`.

The if statement doesn't make too much sense. Just stop fighting instead of dealing no more damage.

Also you can simply calculate who wins the fight. So the loop isn't necessary at all.

Comment: Thank you soo much I did not really though this way thank you! :)